How to avoid loading the full content when i try to get information from blogger post?
I'm trying to get a price from strike inside blogger post to show it in index pages
but it load the full content so if in the post images it load all of it in the background and make the page slow i use this code iso is there another way to achieve that without loading the full content ?
$('.price-offer').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            $id = $this.data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: '/feeds/posts/default/' + $id + '?alt=json',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function(a) {
                var $e = a.entry.content.$t,
                    $c = $("<div>").html($e),
                    $s_price = $c.find('strike:contains("price/")'),
                    $s_off = $c.find('strike:contains("off/")');
                if($s_price.length > 0) {
                    var $text = $s_price.text(),
                        $sp = $text.split('/'),
                        $price = $sp[1];
                    $this.find('.theprice').text($price).parent().addClass('show');
                }
                if($s_off.length > 0) {
                    var $text = $s_off.text(),
                        $sp = $text.split('/'),
                        $off = $sp[1];
                    $this.find('.theoffer').text($off).addClass('show');
                }
            }
        });
    });


For getting specific data only from API you need to have a GraphQL server which will be responsible to give back the data which you have requested.
Or you should ask to your backend developer to give you another API endpoint which will be responsible for sending the data which you need for that scenario.
See about GraphQL here.
